# Return shared view from ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Error-view which should be loaded if an Exception occurs. The Error view is located in:

Views/Shared/Error.cshtml (See attached picture).

[image]

In my Controller, my try-and catch looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Device(string id, bool like, int type)
{
  try
  {
    //code
    return View(viewModel);
  }
  catch (Exception exe)
  {
    return View("Error", exe);
  }
}
```

This works and the correct Error View is displayed. However, I have a ViewComponent which should display the same Error-view.

I have tried the following:

1) Copy the Error-file and pasted it in the same folder as my ViewComponent (Right beneath the Default view). This does not give me an error, but the Default-view is the one being loaded.

2) I have returned the Error view from the shared-folder in the following way:

```
return View("../../../Shared/Error");
```

This as well does not give errors, but the Default view is the one being loaded.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

---

### EDIT

So far I have created a new class

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {

        var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
        var modelMetadata = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
        result.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(
                modelMetadata, context.ModelState);
        result.ViewData.Add("HandleException",
                context.Exception);
        context.Result = result;
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

And in my Error View I added this:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
Layout = "_LayoutCustomer";
Exception ex = ViewData["HandleException"] as Exception;
}
```

And lastly, I added [HandleException] on top of my Controller:

```
[HandleException]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{ 
 //All the actions... 
}
```

To simulate a new Exception, I use:

```
public IActionResult Device(string id, bool like, int type)
{
  try
  {
     throw new Exception();
     //code
     return View(viewModel);
  }
  catch (Exception exe)
  {
     throw;
  }
}
```

This seems to work in the Controller-actions. How can I simulate if it works within the ViewComponent? It gives me an error when I do the same try-catch method.

Comment: why you are handling error on Action Method not in ExceptionFilter

Comment: What do you mean? How does that work?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://stackify.com/aspnet-mvc-error-handling/) for example, chapter HandlerErrorAttribute. Or just let google search that for you.

Comment: You should be handling the error for the view (action method) which includes the view component (not per view component) . Have a global exception handler which handles `OnException` event and return your error view/response from that.

Comment: Please see my latest edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : - Create a Custom ExpectionFilter Attribute

```
public class CustomExpectionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"
            };
        }
    }
```

Step 2 :- Register CustomExpectionFilter in FilterConfig

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomExpectionFilter());
    }
}
```

Step 3 :- Change on

```
public IActionResult Device(string id, bool like, int type)
{
  try
  {
    //code
    return View(viewModel);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
      throw;
  }
}
```

Now when ever error occur in application it will be calling CustomExpection Filter and this filter will handle error and display Error page.

Comment: I created the two classes  CustomExpectionFilter and FilterConfig as you described, and changed my try-catch method. I then simulate a new Exception error with  "throw new Exception()". It gives me an error however, on the line within the catch-method, specifially on "throw;". ??